# Email alert based on monitors going down / coming back up

Tags: elastic-stack, elasticsearch-x-pack, elasticsearch-watcher

I am fairly new to this but I need some help with my watcher setup. - I am using the X-Pack Watchers.

I have setup Heartbeat and I currently have 7 monitors.
i.e
monitor-01
monitor-02
etc.

I need help setting up my exact scenarios, I need help with 3 scenarios:

**Scenario 1**:
If monitor-01 goes offline, I want to send ONLY 1 email to "test@domain.com" with the body of: "Hello there, monitor-01 just went offline! Please check, thanks."

If monitor-02 goes offline, I want the exact same result as above.. I dont want multiple emails alerting me every second / minute if the monitor is down, I only want 1 email.

**Scenario 2**:
If monitor-01 or any my monitors are offline... Every 3 hours, I want a refresh email sent out (I would like the email body to contain how long the specific monitor is down for, i.e monitor down for 120hours 13 minutes). So, if 3 hours pass, I want to send an email to "test@domain.com" with the body of: "Hello there, this is a reminder email that monitor-01 is still offline! Please check, thanks."

**Scenario 3**:
If any of the monitors come back online, I want to send out an email to "test@domain.com" with the body of: "Hello there, great news! monitor-02 is back online. The monitor was down for 7hours 12 minutes. Thanks."

Can someone please assist? I looked everywhere and cannot find the correct syntax to create the above scenarios. These would be scenarios I feel could benefit other members of the community.

P.s, I currently have an advanced watch that I found in the forums but does not match my criteria. Here is the code for it:

```
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "30s"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "heartbeat-*"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "match": {
                  "monitor.status": "down"
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                    "from": "now-50s"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "by_monitors": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "monitor.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gt": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "email_admin": {
      "email": {
        "profile": "standard",
        "from": "noreply@domain.com",
        "to": [
          "test@domain.com"
        ],
        "subject": "Monitor is DOWN: {{ctx.payload.aggregations.by_monitors.buckets.0.key}}",
        "body": {
          "text": "Hello, there is a monitor offline currently. Please check..."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above script I put together sends an email every 30 seconds if a monitor is down which is not what I want.

*Here is what the email says when everything is put together:*
Subject: Monitor is DOWN: [UAT] Test Website
Body: Hello, there is a monitor offline currently. Please check...

Can someone assist with my scenarios? I spent days on this already.. many hours gone in, not much to come out from it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you could look into: [throttling and acknowledging notifications](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/actions.html#actions-ack-throttle)

- **throttling:** once an action is done (eg sending an email), don't do that action again for 3 hours
- **acknowledge:** : in this case you need to call the API to say: "I did receive the notification that watcher01 has found an error, don't send any notifications about it again."